# How specific of a location can a Pokemon Lure be?

Tags: pokemon-go

Hopefully I'm using the right terminology. I'd basically like to know how specific of a location I can make a Pokemon Lure. An Address will not cut it, would need to be like 5ft of my phone or something for it to be useful.

I do not currently play the game and am only interested in this to attract new customers similar to, [Pokemon Go Attracted News Business to NYC Eateries](http://ny.eater.com/2016/7/12/12159204/pokemon-go-nyc-restaurants-money) but I wouldn't be in a storefront with an address.

Comment: Do you have a Poke-stop near your building?  It would more or less be the same as an Ingress portal

Comment: @Taegost uh, no idea as I don't play the game but I wouldn't be using it at my building anyways. And I never played Ingress

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, a pokemon lure can only be at a poke stop.

Comment: @Aequitas so the NYC eateries using the lure are already poke stops? Or there's just a stop near them and then the lure brings the pokemon closer to their spot in the "poke stop" (which in turn brings the customers even closer)?

Comment: A lure when used on a pokestop makes pokemon spawn near the pokestop. It's likely that the eatery you are talking about is a pokestop or one of it's neighbours as the area is quite large, you can be ~30 metres away to still be in range of the pokestop. Most people will want to be nearer to the center though.

Comment: @Aequitas thanks for explaining. Sounds like it won't work for what I had in mind. If you leave your comments as an answer I'd upvote it if you want the rep, and because answers in comments are frowned upon. (Already marked Ekmond's correct)

Comment: Your comments about your intent are very mysterious. Are you planning to rob people :)

Comment: @Montag451 just don't need to publicize a strategy before enacting it. Though like I said, unfortunately it will not work at least at this point in time. Perhaps if they refine it to sell more specific location lures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lure must be used at a PokeStop and it's area is well defined on the in-game map by a pinkish-purply ring that is maybe 2/3 the radius of your player's effect range to gyms and stops.

Comment: Uh, could you answer in terms of feet or meters? I don't know what 2/3 the radius of your players effect means.

Comment: If I had to guess, it'd be maybe 10-15 yards.

Answer (score 4):

Lure's cannot be placed at random locations.
Lure's can only be placed on existing Pokestops*.

* Pokestops are based off of Portal locations from Niantic's game called Ingress; they are not accepting new portals.

So your best bet is to locate a pokestop that can accommodate your business.

For example, If you run a mobile eatery like a hot dog or coffee stand, just locate a nearby pokefarm (collection of pokestops) and setup your stand there and add a Lure to the pokestop as you see fit.