# How to purchase a lure module for my business?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am a business owner. I need "How to step by step instructions to buy a lure module for my business?

Comment: I like this new advertising fad.

Comment: see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273831/how-do-i-use-a-lure-module?rq=1 and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274468/how-specific-of-a-location-can-a-pokemon-lure-be?rq=1

Answer (score 9):

1. Download and install Pokemon GO. Make an account.
2. On the main screen, press the Pokeball (red and white thing at the bottom of your screen).
3. Tap the Shop icon.
4. Scroll down. You will see Lure Modules.
5. Buy them

However, if you don't have any Pokecoins, you need to buy them. Scroll down further to buy some coins to use to buy Lure Modules.

---

To actually use the Lure Module you've bought:

1. Exit out of all menus back to the Map.
2. Tap the PokeStop that you want to Lure to.
3. Touch the white oval-ish shape above the picture.
4. Touch the Lure Module. It will zoom it in.
5. Touch the Lure Module again. The PokeStop will now Lure in customers (hah!).
6. Exit out of all menus back to the Map.